# Show that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is differentiable iff for all $C^{\infty}$ $g : Y \rightarrow R^n$ $g \circ f$ is $C^{\infty}$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose X and Y are topological manifolds.Show that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is differentiable iff for all $C^{\infty}$ $g : Y \rightarrow R^n$ $g \circ f$ is $C^{\infty}$. I think I have an idea about how to do the forward direction.

Let $\{\phi_k,M_k\}_{k \in J}$ and $\{\psi_i,V_i\}_{i \in I}$ be the corresponding charts for X and Y respectively. Since $\{\phi_k,M_k\}$ cover X this means there exists $k \in J$ : $x \in U_j$. Consider $y = h_j(x)$, so we have $x = h_j^{-1}(y)$ which means that $f(x) = f(h_j^{-1}(y))$. I don't have an idea how I can proceed further. I want to show that $g \circ f$ is $C^\infty$. What we know is that since f is differentiable then we have $\psi_i \circ f \circ \phi_k^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$ whenever it is defined. I thought we can link the charts and $g \circ f$ somehow, but I don't have idea about how do we do that.

For the other direction I don't have an idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}$
The forward implication is a consequence of the general fact that composition of smooth maps is again smooth.
To be more precise: Let $X\xrightarrow f Y \xrightarrow g Z$ be a composition of smooth maps between smooth manifolds. Let $\{\phi_j,U_j\}_{j\in J}$ be a smooth atlas of $X$, $\{\psi_i, V_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a smooth atlas for $Y$ and $\{\rho_k,W_k\}_{k\in K}$ be a smooth atlas for $Z$. To show that $g\circ f$ is smooth, we need to show that
$$
\rho_k\circ (g\circ f)\circ \phi_j^{-1}\colon \phi_j(U_j\cap (g\circ f)^{-1}(W_k)) \rightarrow \rho_k(W_k)
$$
is smooth for all $j\in J$, $k\in K$ such that $U_j\cap (g\circ f)^{-1} \neq \varnothing$. Let $j,k$ be such indices. For all $i\in I$ with $f^{-1}(V_i)\cap U_j\cap (g\circ f)^{-1}(W_k)\neq \varnothing$ we see that
$$
\rho_k\circ (g\circ f)\circ \phi_j^{-1} = (\rho_k\circ g\circ \psi_i^{-1}) \circ (\psi_i\circ f\circ \phi_j^{-1})
$$
is a composition of smooth maps $\phi_j(U_j\cap f^{-1}(V_i\cap g^{-1}(W_k))) \rightarrow \rho_k(W_k)$. Now, notice that
$$
\phi_j(U_j\cap (g\circ f)^{-1}(W_k)) = \bigcup_{i\in I}\phi_j(U_j\cap f^{-1}(V_i\cap g^{-1}(W_k))),
$$
so that indeed $\rho_k\circ (g\circ f)\circ \phi_j^{-1}$ is smooth on the whole of $\phi_j(U_j\cap (g\circ f)^{-1}(W_k))$.

Conversely, let $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a (continuous) map such that $g\circ f\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is smooth for all smooth $g\colon Y\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$. Let $\{\phi_j,U_j\}_{j\in J}$ be a smooth atlas of $X$, $\{\psi_i,V_i\}_{i\in I}$ a smooth atlas of $Y$ and $\{\id, \mathbb R^n\}$ a smooth atlas of $\mathbb R^n$. Taking $g:= \psi_i$, we see that
$$
\psi_i\circ f\circ \phi_j^{-1} = \id\circ (g\circ f)\circ \phi_j^{-1}
$$
is smooth for all $i\in I$, $j\in J$ such that $U_j\cap f^{-1}(V_i)\neq \varnothing$. By definition, this means that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: I was wondering where did you use the identity in your proof ? can you explain ?

Comment: I considered $\mathbb R^n$ as a smooth manifold with atlas $\{{\rm id}, \mathbb R^n\}$. Then $g\circ f\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ being smooth means that ${\rm id}\circ (g\circ f)\circ \phi_j^{-1}$ is smooth for all $j$ (by definition of a smooth map between manifolds).